# Arrange the plots nicely on R markdown pdf

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown

I am a newbie at R markdown and am trying to create a pdf with multiple plots.

This should hopefully be an easy fix for a more experienced user.

I am trying to create a nice pdf with multiple plots over 2/3 pages of a pdf.

I have been stuck on this a while and have looked at various older questions/answer on this site.  I am trying to use the patchwork package using the example here:

[image: patchwork]

When I render this to a pdf using R markdown, it only seems to plot on half the page like so:

I have tried playing around with fig.height, out.height="100%", and classoption in the yaml:

```
---
title: "QC Metrics Report.v1"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
geometry: margin=1.5cm
classoption: a4paper, bottom=15mm
---
```

(my code)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE,  message=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(gear)) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 4')


p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
```
````

If I try with the plot_layout function  e.g.

```
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
plot_layout(ncol = 2)
```

half the page is a printout of text (which I don't want)

[image: patchwork with plot_layout]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If the case you are running into is overlapping text when you are arranging the plots then `plot_spacer` and tweaks to some theme options might do the trick.

````
---
title: "My Report"
subtitle: "Report.v1"
author: "John Doe"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
   pdf_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.align = 
"center")
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(gapminder)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)
````

```r
   my_countries <- c("Zambia", "Malawi", "Mozambique", "Tanzania", "Kenya") 
    
    east_africa <- gapminder %>% 
      filter(country %in% my_countries) %>%
      mutate(country = fct_reorder2(country, year, lifeExp)) # reorder for plotting
    
    
    
    bar <- east_africa %>% 
      filter(year == max(year)) %>%  # most recent year only
      ggplot(aes(x = country, y = lifeExp, fill = country)) +
      geom_col(width = 0.75, alpha = 0.9) +
      geom_text(
        aes(label = number(lifeExp, 0.1)),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
        color = "white",
        fontface = "bold",
        size = 5
        ) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(0.01, 0.05)) +  # remove extra space between bars and x-axis labels
      labs(y = "Life Expectancy (years)") +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 16) + 
      theme(
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7, angle = 45),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()
        )
#> Warning: `expand_scale()` is deprecated; use `expansion()` instead.
    
    
    
    line <- east_africa %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = lifeExp, color = country)) +
      geom_line(lwd = 1.25, key_glyph = "timeseries") +  # for those cute glyphs in the legend
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
      labs(y = "Life Expectancy (years)") +
      theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
      theme(
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title.y.left = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(t = 30)
      )
    
    
    tab <- east_africa %>% 
      filter(year == max(year)) %>% 
      transmute(
        Country = country, 
        Population = comma(pop),
        `GDP per capita` = dollar(gdpPercap, 1),
        `Life Expectancy` = number(lifeExp, 0.1),
        ) %>% 
      arrange(Country) %>% 
      tableGrob(theme = ttheme_minimal(base_size = 10), rows = NULL)
    
    layout <- bar + plot_spacer() + tab + plot_spacer() + line + plot_spacer()
    
    layout +
      plot_annotation(
      title = "Life Expectancy of Selected Countries\n in East Africa",
      caption = "Source: gapminder: Data from Gapminder
                 github.com/jennybc/gapminder
                 gapminder.org/data/",
      theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
      )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**updated**

If the case you are running into is that you have lots of code stuff in your actual pdf then use `results = 'hide'`

```
    p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
      geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
      ggtitle('Plot 1')
    
    p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
      ggtitle('Plot 2')
    
    p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
      geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
      ggtitle('Plot 3')
    
    p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
      geom_bar(aes(gear)) + 
      facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
      ggtitle('Plot 4')
    
    
    p1 + p2 + p3 + p4
```

Comment: Sorry, @JoshAllen I edited my question but it looks like you have answered the before edit question

Comment: I just updated my answer. It looks like you just needed to edit your chunk options a bit

Comment: it is still only plotting on the top half of the page (as in the first picture in my question)

Comment: It could be that you need to change the aspect ratios via `fig.height`  or `fig.width` in the chunk options. Alternatively `heights` or widths within `plot_layout` . If it is an issue related to your images aren't appearing where they are supposed to after you are writing the report then you may need to add `fig.pos = !H` after adding extra_dependencies: ["float"] to your yaml

Comment: I have tried playing around with  fig.width, fig.height and out.height="100%".              I did: output:
  pdf_document: default
  extra_dependencies: ["float"]knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = "!H") and it is still only plotting to the top half of the page on a pdf

Comment: So it kind of depends what you are looking for. `fig.pos =!H` is just a LaTeX option that fixes the position of the figure like if you were writing in MS word. If you just want a plot that is super big than you are gonna be in the `fig.height = 28` territory.

Comment: I want to make a plot of 
4 plots (either 2 by 2 or 4 by 1) on the 2nd page of my pdf. I have worked out how to make a nice 2 by 1 plot on the first page ( my original question) using par(mfrow) bit this isn't working for the four plots